# Show a string inside an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Javascript

```
var questionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    question: String,
    Answers: [{
        answerSummary: String,
        answer: String,
        answerExtended: String,
        image: String,
        source: String,
        date: String,
    }],
});  

var question = mongoose.model("question", questionsSchema);
```

I want to show the string `answerSummary`. I have tried this with no success:

```
<%= question.Answers.answerSummary%>
```

Help?

Comment: Have you tried <%= question.Answers[0].answerSummary%>
like this

Answer (score 0):

Answers is an array, so you must specify explicitly which position of the array do you want to get. 
 `question.Answers[0].answerSummary`